# Effective way to find similar data pattern from a large data set

Tags: algorithm, large-data

I have a large data set (millions records) in database, a simplified example as:

`6,1,3,5,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,3,1,3,5,4,6,3,4,6,4,5,7,4,5,0,8,... (millions records)`

Here each number represents a key value of a row.

I need find all occurrences of `1,3,5`. The straight way is to iterate the whole data set and check the three successive rows in each iteration.

Is there more effective algorithm to do this?

Comment: For larger search string, KMP might improve the search performance. I'm not sure if this applies to three elements. If you search the same (or similar) database several times, you can save the results of previous searches.

Comment: When it comes to finding all occurrences of something in an unsorted collection, O(N) is as good as you can get.

Comment: What does `in each iteration` mean? There should be only one iteration through the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find only 3 element subsequence the most afective way is to iterate the whole data.

It is easy to proof: You must all serching algorithms check whole array.

In this algorithm you do this max 3 times. It is the best complexity you can get.